# Get rid of "welcome to your new inbox" in gmail

Tags: gmail

The message and graphics for "welcome to your new inbox" has been in my gmail app since priority inbox showed up,  and I can't get rid of it.

[image: screenshot]

What to do?

I am on Lollipop, but the problem was also there before I upgraded both OS and the GMail app.

Comment: it should be gone now.

Answer (score 1):

Clear the Gmail app's data & cache in Settings > Applications.

It achieves your desired result - getting rid of that message permanently after a single swipe. I can't tell you why, only that I had the same problem, found the solution above online and that it worked for me - so I came to report back on a result that had no solution posted.